# Как сохранять параметры пользователя при http basic auth?

Tags: javascript, axios, auth

Авторизуюсь на удаленном api, настроена basic auth. Метод авторизации:

```
auth() {
const token = Buffer.from(`${email}:${psw}`, 'utf8').toString('base64')
      var config = {
        method: "get",
        url:
          "http://....",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Basic ${token}`,
        }
      };
      axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

При авторизации через браузер через стандартную форму учетные данные сохраняются и в дальнейшем можно обращаться к серверу без авторизации какое-то время.
При отправке запроса, авторизация также успешна, но чтобы обратиться к этому же роуту или другому нужно опять передавать заголовок авторизации или возникает ошибка:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized).
Где можно сохранить заголовок? Или как правильно организовать работу?

Answer (score 2):

```
axios.defaults.headers.authorization = `Basic ${token}`
```

Comment: Спасибо. При обновлении страницы в дальнейшем нужно будет повторно передавать данные авторизации?
Или я могу сохранить токен? Как сделать это наиболее правильно?